# Formatting syntax in SQL

Tags: sql

[SQL create table code from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fl1Z.png)

The above is from a popular SQL beginners book.

Do new variables need to be on a new line?

Is it ok to have a combo of upper and lower case?

What is the standard formating?

Comment: This is clearly *not* opinion-based.

Comment: "This is clearly not opinion-based"—but it also clearly has three questions in one, which is the definition of "too broad" according to Stack Overflow's canned close reasons.

Answer (score 2):

- *Do new variables need to be on a new line?*

No.

- *Is it ok to have a combo of upper and lower case?*

It is acceptable, but semmatically not nice. Depends how you mix them.

- *What is the standard formating?*

There are no real standards for that. Just make it readable. I for example use upper-case for every SQL command, and lowercase for everything else... like:

```
SELECT something FROM something WHERE something
```

but

```
select SOMETHING from SOMETHING where SOMETHING
```

is a valid SQL syntax and will do **exactly** the same. As well as:

```
seLect sOMEthing
FrOm somethinG WhERE
SOMETHIng
```